EDIT: search rows of table for values greater than or less than an input
The code below works fine for searching a table. There is a
single input box (id="name") in the html part, the table, then the code:
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#name").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#data_table tr").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text()
            .toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});

I have added four input boxes, (id ="strain", id="acc", id="length" and id="GC"), and
corresponding thead entries to give 5 columns. The tbody is now:
Al
P301
CP123
1000
50.1
Mike
U123
AP456
2500
50.1
Mike
C567
AP
3300
52.0
Mike
P511
AP789
1000
55.5
The modified code is:
   $("#name,#strain,#acc").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#data_table tr").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text()
            .toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});

//repeat for length
   $("#length").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#data_table tr").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text()
            .toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});

//repeat for GC
   $("#GC").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#data_table tr").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text()
            .toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});

The last two rows of the table correspond to length and GC. The code for these has been separated from that of the first 3 items, and works well. However, I would like to be able to search for values of length greater than or less than a value entered into the length search box, and similarly for GC.

[Edit], don't repost.
